# Modify page title and subtitle with a plugin

Tags: plugins, filters, shortcode, wp-title

How can I build a plugin which will modify a title (header) of the page?

I built one generic page which uses shortcodes to display relevant information based on url parameters, but I can't use shortcodes to generate dynamic headers.

So I tried to add "the_title" filter, but it won't update the header, it only updates title in links to another pages:

```
function sn_training_title($title){

    return $title."...";
}

add_filter( 'the_title', 'sn_training_title' );
```

here is how it looks:
[image]

Comment: Usually `the_content()` runs after `the_title()` in the `page.php` template.

Comment: How does that impact? I'm very new to the WP development

Comment: i.e. the title is displayed before the shortcode is generated in `the_content()`. Also something strange is your is_page check.

Answer (score 2):

In simple words the problem with your approach is this:

The title kind of already is on his way from your server to the browser of your users when WordPress starts thinking about the content where your shortcodes are in. So this is too late.

Also if you look at what the [`is_page` function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) takes as a parameter...

> Page ID, Page Title or Page Slug

... you see that a shortcode isn't an option to use.

So if you are already familiar with using URL parameters why not use those directly in the filter above instead of trying to go through shortcodes?

Comment: I understand that I cannot use shortcodes in the title, but filter "the_title" won't modify the title of the page when viewing it as a single page, it only modifies links to other pages, not the one that I'm viewing at the moment

Comment: I updated my snippet to make it less confusing